# Can't run Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

This is the same issue as another user, but due to protection, I could not add to it (I am a new user and don't have 300 reputation) and none of the responses were solutions to the problem. Unlike that user, I still want Windows 8 so I don't want to install over it.  I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 in a partition drive D (the hard drive came partitioned).  Based on problems with Windows 8 reported by other users, I installed with Secure Boot disabled. After I restarted my computer and selected the Ubuntu option.  I got an error message:

Starting Windows didn't succeed. The reason may be changing software.
To solve this problem:

1. Insert installation disc of Windows and reboot pc
2. Choose language settings and click Next
3. Use Repair
   If you don't own this disk contact with the administrator.

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
 State: 0xc000007b

Information: Could not load application or Operating System because of the lack of the required file or errors in this file

Windows 8 still boots if I choose that option, but when I choose Ubuntu I get that error message.  How can I make Ubuntu work on Windows 8?

Comment: Have you used Wubi to install Ubuntu?

Comment: according to the error message, yes he did.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you have tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer).
Wubi cannot work with preinstalled Windows8 (because Wubi is incompatible with GPT).

Please install Ubuntu the standard way (on its own partition). See [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Pop in your Ubuntu Live-CD, install the package [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and start it.

It might not directly answer your question, but boot-repair really solves 99% of boot problems.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I do not have a Live-CD, is there another way to do the boot repair?

Comment: The Boot-Repair utility cannot help in this case (Windows8+Wubi).